# Unable to disable button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have the below JQuery code to disable the "Submit" button when the page is ready , but when the page finishes loading the button still active, here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
 });
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Are you sure you have included jQuery?

Comment: works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ovtajgok/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

As the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) state (emphasis mine):

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected,
>   or **disabled** state of form elements, **use the .prop() method**.

Answer (score 1):

Since jquery 1.6, you need to use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for attributes that are solely presence-based (like disabled, checked, selected etc).

This should work:

```
$('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: You can still use .attr("disabled", "disabled"); with jquery 1.6 or higher version. It's just that its obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

use `.prop("disabled", true)` instead